# Plus sign in the middle of a ring

Tags: chemfig

I would like to draw in `chemfig` the following picture:

[image]

But I am struggling with the "+" sign in the middle of the circle. Is there a way to draw it? Thank you!

What I have so far is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  N**[0,-150,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]5(
    (-R)-(-R^1)-[,,1,2]{+\hspace{0.3cm}}|{O}-[,,2,1]--
  )
}

\end{document}
```

which does the work, but I really don't like the way it is done (e.g. it does not scale).

Comment: You should post your code, so that we could easily have a starting point. A minimal working example would be great (starting from `\documentclas…` and ending with `\end{document}`).

Comment: @Manuel Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following examples uses that the `tikz` code for the arc uses a center node named `arccenter`. The `tikz` option argument for the `\draw` command of the arc can be used with option `late options` to put a label in the center:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  N**[0,-144,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,
       late options={name=arccenter,label=center:+}]
  5( (-R)-(-R^1)-O--- )
}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. But I could not find it in the tikz manual. Great!

Comment: @pisoir: `arccenter` is not a `tikz` property of `arc`, but a node name set by the internals of `chemfig`.

Comment: Just for the sake of correctness… shouldn't it be `…[0,-144,…` instead of `…[0,-150,…`? I know nothing about chemistry.

Comment: @Manuel: I agree with you and have changed the angle from -150 to -144 = -(360/5)*2.

Comment: As of chemfig 1.56, the interface has been changed. See modified version: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553989/updated-solution-to-charge-in-center-of-ring-using-chemfig

Answer (score 8):

I'd use an invisible bond pointing to the center of the ring (with a relative angle) to place the plus. Something like `(-[::126,,,,draw=none]\oplus)`, possibly scaled a bit. On the other hand I do like Heiko's answer better than mine :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  R-[:36]N
  **[216,360,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]5(
    -(-[::126,.6,,,draw=none]\oplus)
     (-R|_1)
    -O(-[,,,,draw=none]X^{-})
    ---
  )
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In a bind, you can slap it on after the fact with a `\stackinset`.  The syntax here means that the inset item (a bold `+`) is placed 10pt to the right of center, and 15pt above center on the underlying `\chemfig`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\stackinset{c}{10pt}{c}{15pt}{\textbf{+}}{%
\chemfig{
  N**[0,-150,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]5(
    (-R)-(-R^1)-[,,1,2]{}|{O}-[,,2,1]--
  )
}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]