# Use of # in align block

Tags: align, chemfig

I have a `chemfig` command which involves the use of `#`. It compiles properly on itself.

```
\chemfig{**[135,405,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]6(----#(,0pt)\chembelow[2.5em]{}{+}(-#(0pt)[3]H)(-#(0pt)[1]NO_3)-#(0pt)-)}
```

But when I put it into the align block, pdfLaTeX gives error.

```
\begin{align*}
\chemfig{**[135,405,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]6(----#(,0pt)\chembelow[2.5em]{}{+}(-#(0pt)[3]H)(-#(0pt)[1]NO_3)-#(0pt)-)}
\end{align*}
```

The error message is here: http://pastebin.com/3FLzX4RP

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{chemfig}

\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\chemfig{**[135,405,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]6(----#(,0pt)\chembelow[2.5em]{}{+}(-#(0pt)[3]H)(-#(0pt)[1]NO_3)-#(0pt)-)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

In `chemfig`, `#` is used to adjust the bond shortening. The following example is from the [chemfig documentation, pg. 6](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/chemfig/chemfig_doc_en.pdf)
[image: Example from chemfig doc]

I've tried using `\#(0pt)`, but instead of adjusting the bond, it outputs the string directly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.What does `#` do in chemfig? Perhaps it's required literally, i.e. `\#` within align?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer , thank you for the reminder. I have updated the the question.

Comment: [Related, for the plus sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156483/plus-sign-in-the-middle-of-a-ring). By the way, aren't the angles `150,390`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\chemfig` command relies on category code changes, in particular it changes `#` to an “other character” (category code 12). Such commands cannot appear in the argument to another command.

While `equation` and `equation*` are safe on this respect, `align*` isn't: the multiline alignment environments of `amsmath` absorb their content as the argument to a command. You'd have the same problem trying `\fbox{\chemfig{...}}`.

Using `align*` as a substitute for `equation*` is not recommended, so in the example case `equation*` would do. But if you really need a multiline environment, here's a trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,chemfig}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chemfigon}{\begingroup\@makeother\#}
\let\chemfigoff\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chemfig{**[135,405,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]6(----#(,0pt)\chembelow[2.5em]{}{+}(-#(0pt)[3]H)(-#(0pt)[1]NO_3)-#(0pt)-)}

\chemfigon
\begin{align*}
\chemfig{**[135,405,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]6(----#(,0pt)\chembelow[2.5em]{}{+}(-#(0pt)[3]H)(-#(0pt)[1]NO_3)-#(0pt)-)}
\end{align*}
\chemfigoff

\end{document}
```

This makes `#` an “other character” before the input is grabbed as an argument.

[image]

Comment: `\chemfig{**[150,390,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,late options={name=arccenter,label=center:+}]6(----#(,0pt)(-#(0pt)[3]H)(-#(0pt)[1]NO_3)-#(0pt)-)}` this is more elegant in my opinion.

Comment: And this one, without `#`, should be prefered: `\chemfig{**[135,405,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]6(----(-[3]H)(-[1]NO_3)(-[6,,,,draw=none]+)--)}`

Answer (score 3):

In theory, `\chemfig{<code>}` can be written in the argument of a macro since `\CF@chemfig@iv` does a `\scantokens` of the `<code>`. Unfortunately, there is a bug because via `\scantokens`, `#` becomes `##` in the argument of a macro and this behaviour is not taken into account by `\chemfig`.

For example, if you write `\fbox{\chemfig{A-#(0pt)B}}`, the code of the molecule becomes `A-##(0pt)B`, where `#` is catcode 12. The bug is in `\CF@grab@bondoffset`: this macro expects a `(` juste after the first `#`. And this is not the case when `\chemfig` is in the argument of a macro.

Here is a fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\makeatletter
\def\CF@grab@bondoffset#1(#2)#3\@nil{%
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \else
        \CF@if@instr{#2},%
            {\CF@analyse@bondoffset#2\@nil}%
            {\def\CF@start@offset{#2}}%
    \fi
    \def\CF@remain@afterbond{#3}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\fbox{\chemfig{A-#(0pt)B}}

\chemfig{A-#(0pt)B}
\end{document}
```

[image]