# How do I get a centered charge into the ring with chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

I would like to draw a Sydnone with chemfig. How do I get the -+ into the ring?

[image: Sydnone]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}  
\chemfig{N**5(-[,,1]\chembelow{N}{H}-[,,1]-[,3,1](=[,1,1]O)-[,3,]O-[,3])}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: With the code available, people can just complete the code to have the charge. Without any code, all-purpose answer would be: Use tikz to place the charge inside the ring. Right now, it is impossible to me more specific.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156500/21930

Comment: Also related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229514/use-of-in-align-block#comment541997_229516