# Updated solution to charge in center of ring using chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

So, essentially I want to do exactly what is shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156483/plus-sign-in-the-middle-of-a-ring/156500). This has worked beautifully for me using miktex under Windows, but now I'm working under Ubuntu and have just installed the 2020 version of TeX Live. Here, I get the error message `Package pgf Error: No shape named 'arccenter' is known ...`. So I would interpret this in a way that some of the internal workings of `chemfig` have changed so that the center of the ring is no longer called 'arccenter'? Is there a new name for that node that I could specify?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig[atom sep=.9cm]{**[,,,late options={name=arccenter,label=center:+}]5(-----)}

\end{document}
```

(I would have preferred to just add a comment to the existing question, however, I don't have enough reputation...

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, but not being documented doesn't mean it's not there. This has worked before. And still does, but only on my Windows machine

Comment: Strange situation, but couldn't you make an alert for this bug on Ubuntu on a specific site? +1 for your question.

Comment: @Sebastiano I would be very surprised if this was Ubuntu related. Like I said, I think most likely its's the chemfig version

Comment: Btw. in that question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156483/plus-sign-in-the-middle-of-a-ring/156500 you have also answers which do not require arccenter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Until `chemfig` v1.55, node `arccenter` is defined per arced ring.
- In `chemfig` v1.56 (updated on 13 July 2020), nodes at the center of rings are named `cyclecenter<n>`. Here `<n>` is `1, 2, 3, ...` which indicates the center of `<n>`th ring in one `\chemfig`.
- For source code changes, see [diff of `chemfig.tex`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/chemfig/chemfig.tex?limit_changes=0&r1=55828&r2=55827&pathrev=55828) between v1.55 and v1.56 (open and search for `arccenter`), from TeX Live's SVN repository.
- For official documentation and usage examples about `cyclecenter<n>`, see [manual of `chemfig` v1.56](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf), section 12.6.

Therefor, with `chemfig` v1.56, just replace node name `arccenter` with `cyclecenter1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{**[0,-150,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,
       late options={name=cyclecenter1,label=center:+}]5(-----)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting and complete answer.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for the solution and also the pointers on how to approach this in the future! There's an interesting combination of typos in the current docs describing this approach :)

Comment: @NoBullsh1t You can report typos found in package manual to https://framagit.org/unbonpetit/chemfig/-/issues. Or you can mention them here and I can  report for you.

Comment: Stumbled about it after updating to TeXlive 2020, thanks for clarifying ...

Answer (score 1):

I have used TeXLive 2019 (Papeeria) OS W8.1 and this MWE works correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{**[0,-150,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,
       late options={name=arccenter,label=center:+}]5(-----)}
\end{document}
```

[image]