# Is there a possibility to see the (tikz) code a command produces?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553989/updated-solution-to-charge-in-center-of-ring-using-chemfig). If I wanted to figure this out by myself, the easiest way would be to inspect the actual (tikz) code the `\chemfig` command produces. I wonder whether something like that would be possible? I imagine one of the problems would be how to specify how deeply the command should be expanded?!

Comment: Did you try '\tracingcommands' and '\tracingmacros"? Sometimes they su** but at least they can give you a hint...

Comment: Try [`unravel` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unravel/unravel.pdf). Though for complex packages like `chemfig` which is based on `tikz`, step by step expansion will just confuse you.

Comment: \meaning will give your the first few steps.  Easiest is to find the sty file and search for \chemfig.  There may be multiple definitions, or layers and layers of other commands to work through.  If your editor as a Search in Files feature, try searching the entire tex directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9.tex)